# Определить 5 идущих подряд любых символов регулярным выражением

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.

Код мой:

```
Regex t3regex = new Regex("(.){5}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Тут я могу определить, вообще есть ли 5 любых символов. Но не пойму, как "запомнить" предыдущий символ, чтобы потом посчитать количество его вхождений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю для варианта с пятью проще сделать так:

```
Regex t3regex = new Regex("(.)\\1\\1\\1\\1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

`\<номер>` - это доступ к группе

[Элементы языка регулярных выражений — краткий справочник | Microsoft Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) - вот где можно мудрости по этому вопросу набраться :-)

Comment: Ругается чего-то на "1"...
Вот ошибка: 
error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: Да, точно, задублируйте слешь

Comment: Да, и единицу одну убрать надо. А то начинает искать с 6...
Вот так: 

Regex t3regex = new Regex("(.)\\1\\1\\1\\1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);